# Why am I getting a NullPointerException and no display the component i added?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Below, you will find the error message I received. The output show only the `JFrame` with no content.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1043)
  at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
  at gui.<init>(gui.java:37)
  at gui.main(gui.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

Code follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class gui extends JFrame {
    JPanel p1;
    JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3,tf4;
    JLabel lbl1,lbl2,lbl3,lbl5,lbl6,lbl7,lbl8,lbl9,lbl10;
    JTextArea txtMessage;
    JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        gui f = new gui();
        f.setTitle("RSA.");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(700,500);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public gui() {
        lbl1 = new JLabel("Enter first prime number : ");
        lbl2 = new JLabel("Enter second prime number: ");
        lbl3 = new JLabel("Enter the message to be send : ");
        tf1 = new JTextField(15);
        tf2 = new JTextField(15);
        txtMessage = new JTextArea("Please enter",5,20);
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(lbl1);
        p1.add(tf1);
        p1.add(lbl2);
        p1.add(tf2);
        p1.add(lbl3);
        p1.add(txtMessage);

    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    p1.add(lbl1);
    p1.add(tf1);
    p1.add(lbl2);
    p1.add(tf2);
    p1.add(lbl3);
    p1.add(txtMessage);
    }
}
```

I will appreciate for those who give the solution to me.Thanks
After edit and the output is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Name your class `Gui` or `GUI`, not `gui`... Or better yet: `RSAEncryptionFrame`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this line in the constructor:

```
this.add(p1);
```

Comment: This would need to be added to the `gui` method actually, because `p1` isn't constructed until halfway through that method.

Comment: did you run it? I did  but maybe I switched something else by accident

Comment: actually nvm, `gui` _is_ the constructor. (The name capitalization tricked me.)

Answer (score 1):

`lbl3` is never set to a value other than `null`, you set `lbl2` two times instead:

```
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter second prime number: ");
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter the message to be send : ");
```

replace that with

```
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter second prime number: ");
lbl3=new JLabel("Enter the message to be send : ");
```

Comment: Work,but just display the window with no content. The component i added to JPanel and set for border work nothing

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initializing `lbl3` in `gui`'s constructor. I'm guessing this is a typo - you have two lines initializing `lbl2`:

```
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter second prime number: ");
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter the message to be send : ");
```

Just change the second one to `lbl3`, and you should be OK:

```
lbl2=new JLabel("Enter second prime number: ");
lbl3=new JLabel("Enter the message to be send : "); // here
```

Comment: Work,but just display the window with no content. The component i added to JPanel and set for border work nothing.